# The function in the script is not being called

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have the function 'fetchdetails' in  my script which is not being called. What mistake am I doing?

/Visualforce/

```
<apex:page controller="accountPicklist">
     <script>
         function fetchDetails(){ 
                var objValue = document.getElementById('aid');
                alert('!!!objValue'+objValue);
                MyFunc(objValue);
         }                                
    </script> 

     <apex:form id="fm">
     <apex:actionFunction name="MyFunc" action="{!Getdetails}">
            <apex:param name="objValue" value="" /> 
     </apex:actionFunction>  
        <apex:outputPanel id="AccountDetails">   
          <apex:pageBlock title="Account Name">

               <apex:selectList id="aid" value="{!accId}" size="1" > 
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!AccountNames}"  />
                </apex:selectList>

               <apex:commandButton value="Select" onclick="fetchdetails()" reRender = "OpportunityDetails" />
           </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:outputPanel>  

        <apex:outputPanel id="OpportunityDetails" style="display:block">
          <apex:pageBlock title="Opportunity Details">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!opplist}" var="opp">
              <apex:column value="{!opp.id}" headerValue="ID"/>
              <apex:column value="{!opp.name}" headerValue="Name"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>

          </apex:pageBlock>

        </apex:outputPanel>
     </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

/Controller class/

```
public with sharing class accountPicklist{

      public list<Opportunity> oppList{get;set;}

      public string accId{get;set;}
      public list<Account> accList{get;set;}
      public string accId1{get;set;}

      public accountPicklist(){
                oppList = new list<Opportunity>();


      }

      public List<SelectOption> getAccountNames() {
         List<SelectOption> accOptions= new List<SelectOption>();
         accOptions.add( new SelectOption('','--Select--'));
         for( Account acc : [select Id,name from Account ] ) {
                 accOptions.add( new SelectOption(acc.Id,acc.name)); 
         }
         return accOptions;
      }

      public void getdetails(){
          system.debug('*****************************'+accId1);
          accId1 = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('objValue');
          oppList = [select id, name from Opportunity where AccountId =: accId1];
          system.debug('*****************************'+oppList);
      }
}
```

Comment: add `reRender = "none"` into your commandbutton

Comment: Nope, not working

Comment: may be due to script error. Check for them with firebug or similar tool. According to the VF id generation for DOM elements, sure there is no any elements with id **aid**. So get the id of your selectList by inspecting it again with firebug or your favorite inspecting tool.

Comment: there are two things. 1. as highfive said. aid will have a different id after rendering so please get id of that 2. add status to your actionfunction.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm new to this. How do I get the id of aid? I just print it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers and comments. The only change that I did to my code was I changed `var objValue = document.getElementById('aid');` to

```
var objValue = document.getElementById('$component.aid');
```

and it worked. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

If you debug with Developer Tool in chrome , you will see javascript error saying 'fetchdetails is not defined'

I notice that the function name is fetchDetails while you calling for fetchdetails .

Change to code below, and it will trigger the script.

```
 <apex:commandButton value="Select" onclick="fetchDetails();" reRender = "OpportunityDetails" />
```